# How to make Analog to parse only one week of logs?

Tags: windows-server-2003, log-files, logging, analytics

On my windows server, I use analog to parse my log files and analyze them.
The logs are daily and named as exYYMMDD.log
How i can set in the analog cfg file to parse only one week of logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started using analog and reportmagic myself..

I grabbed this out of the howto in the docs:

> You can also include the date in the
>   LOGFILE name, by using the following
>   codes.
>
> %D  date of month 
>  
>   %m  month name, in English
>  
>   %M  month number 
>   %y  two-digit year 
>   %Y  four-digit year 
>   %H  hour 
>   %n minute 
>   %w  day of week, in English
>
> So for example,
>   LOGFILE access_log%Y%M.log
>
> will look for the logfile
>   access_log200109.log, if it's
>   September 2001. The date used is
>   actually the TO date if one was
>   specified, and otherwise the time of
>   the start of the program. So for
>   example, you can look at all of last
>   month's logfiles with the commands

Which should give you a little help in setting up exactly *what* logfiles you wish to parse. In addition there's this corresponding entry, that details the "TO" and "FROM" dates:

> There is also one other pair of commands which belongs in this category, namely the FROM > and TO commands. These specify a time period to restrict the analysis to. The simplest 
>   usage of these commands is FROM yyMMdd or FROM yyMMdd:hhmm, where yy represents the last > two digits of the year (analog assumes that the year is between 1970 and 2069), MM 
>   represents the month, dd is the date, hh the hour, and mm the minute. So, for example, to > analyse only requests from 1st July 1999 to 1pm on 15th June 2000 I would use the 
>   configuration
>
> FROM 990701
>   TO   000615:1300
>
> Alternatively, each of the components can be preceded by + or - to represent time 
>   relative to the time at which the program was invoked. In this case, the date can have 
>   more than 2 digits. This allows constructions like
>
> FROM -01-00+01   # from tomorrow last year
>   TO -00-0131  # to the end of last month (OK even if last month didn't have 31 days)
>   FROM -00-00-112
>   TO   -00-00-01  # statistics for the last 16 weeks
>   FROM -00-00-00:-06+01  # statistics for the last 6 hours
>
> There are command line abbreviations +F and +T for the FROM and TO commands; for example, 
>   +T-00-00-01:1800 looks at statistics until 6pm yesterday. -F and -T turn off the from and 
>   to, as do FROM OFF and TO OFF.

With those, you can likely derive what you need. I'd hazard an educated guess that your answer lays within the "FROM" and "TO" .cfg entries.

As one more alternative, you could always skip those above and simply write a batch script that will move/archive or delete the previous week of logfiles -out_ of the default "\LogFiles\W3SVC1" location to say, something like "D:\IIS-Logfiles-Archive", and *then* run the analog analyzer for the day. Some pseudocode that might help you get started and moving in the right direction would be:

*(and again, this is PSEUDO-code. Rough, ugly and fits like a wet wool sweater. There probably isn't a need to delete the directory, but I'm cribbing from another script that I use, mmmkay? :)*

> net stop all_your_webservices_here
>   cd C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1
>   del /f /q *.*
>   cd c:\
>   rd /s /q C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1
>   mkdir C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1
>   net start all_your_webservices_here
>   "C:\Program Files\analog 6.0\analog.exe" && rmagic

*Sorry, that last little bit in there is if you've got reportmagic installed and running as well. If you don't, I HIGHLY recomend it. Makes analog pretty, impresses management. Mmm, Mmmm good. Like soup or something. :)*

That being said, I'm going to guess that you're wanting to restrict analyzing to a week because it's taking forever for analog to parse your logs. (This is a totally random guess, and colored by my opinion, because I sorta/kinda saw the same thing when initially setting it up :)

Be advised, once you parse a set of logfiles, (say a few days worth, or a week's worth) it may take a while, however re-running analog to examine any following logfiles is *extremely* quick. To summarize; create a scheduled task for analog to run once a day and it while the initial run will take some time, each successive run will be much faster than the first.

HTH, mate...

Comment: wow, thank you!
I will use FROM -00-00-7
TO -00-00-01, thank you.
i have also reportmagic, i love it

Comment: Hey, no worries mate.. You're very welcome, glad I could lend a hand!

Comment: for who is interested: you have to write FROM -00-00-07
TO -00-00-01, with TWO digits, otherwise the input will be ignored

Answer (score 1):

Dude, I just thought of this after posting. Maybe this will help a little more, since most of the links to, "Here's how *Bob* did his config, and here's how *Jerry* did his here, which is nice and all, etc." are no longer valid.

In the hopes that it can help you out a little more, here's my analog.cfg file:

> "#" The below WAS production, and became a test.
>   "#"
>   "#" LOGFILE C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1\ex%y%M%D.*
>   "#" 
>   "#" It worked, but only gave us one logfile at a time.
>   "#" 
>   "#" The below is a test.
>   "#"
>   "#" LOGFILE C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1*.log
>   "#" 
>   "#" The above worked, because we want to parse ALL the logfiles,
>   "#" sequentially. Sticking with this for now.
>   "#" 
>   
>   "#" 
>   "#" This line records how long it took to generate reports.
>   "#"
>   
>   RUNTIME ON
>   
>   "#"
>   "#" This line re-sets the logfile to localtime. Took a while to
>   "#" figure out as well.
>   "#"
>   
>   LOGTIMEOFFSET -360
>   LOGFILE C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1*.log
>   
>   "#"
>   "#" This line tells "analog" to dump it's output into "computer readable"
>   "#" format, for reportmagic to use. If we didn't use this, we would 
>   "#" tell it to output it in html format for human, or browser-readable
>   "#" format.
>   "#"
>   
>   OUTPUT COMPUTER
>   
>   "#"
>   "#" This line tells analog specifically WHERE to dump it's output.
>   "#"
>   
>   OUTFILE D:\inetpub\wwwroot\stats\report.dat
>   
>   "#"
>   "#" These lines tell analog where the charts go.
>   "#"
>   
>   LOCALCHARTDIR "D:\inetpub\wwwroot\stats\charts\%Y.%M."
>   CHARTDIR "charts/%Y.%M." 
>   
>   "#"
>   "#" These lines set the pretty text in the html
>   "#"
>   
>   HOSTNAME "[My company's intranet]"
>   HOSTURL http://mycompany_intranet
>   
>   "#"
>   "#" These lines tell analog how to resolve it's hostnames. We
>   "#" need to work on these some, because the "dnscache.txt" file
>   "#" simply continues to grow as this runs and results in us having
>   "#" to exert some maintenance. I was unable to get it to resolve
>   "#" DIRECTLY from the network, however I'm sure that it's possible
> .
>   "#"
>   
>   DNS WRITE
>   DNSFILE dnscache.txt
>   DNSLOCKFILE dnslock.txt
>   DNSGOODHOURS 8
>   
>   "#" 
>   "#" Here's some pre-set, pre-module-load options that we need to set in the very beginning. 
>   "#" They're kinda like the ones above, but you can consider them meta-tags or meta-variables.
>   "#"
>   
>   REQLINKINCLUDE pages
>   REFLINKINCLUDE *
>   REDIRREFLINKINCLUDE *
>   FAILREFLINKINCLUDE *
>   SUBBROW */*
>   SUBTYPE *.gz,*.Z
>   
>   "#" Add whichever of these types of pages you have on your server, or others.
>   
>   PAGEINCLUDE *.shtml
>   PAGEINCLUDE *.html
>   PAGEINCLUDE *.asp
>   PAGEINCLUDE *.jsp
>   PAGEINCLUDE *.js
>   PAGEINCLUDE *.cfm
>   PAGEINCLUDE *.css
>   PAGEINCLUDE *.pl
>   PAGEINCLUDE *.php
>   PAGEINCLUDE *.swf
>   
>   TYPEALIAS .html    ".html [Hypertext Markup Language]"
>   TYPEALIAS .htm     ".htm  [Hypertext Markup Language]"
>   TYPEALIAS .shtml   ".shtml [Server-parsed HTML]"
>   TYPEALIAS .ps      ".ps   [PostScript]"
>   TYPEALIAS .gz      ".gz   [Gzip compressed files]"
>   TYPEALIAS .tar.gz  ".tar.gz [Compressed archives]"
>   TYPEALIAS .jpg     ".jpg  [JPEG graphics]"
>   TYPEALIAS .jpeg    ".jpeg [JPEG graphics]"
>   TYPEALIAS .gif     ".gif  [GIF graphics]"
>   TYPEALIAS .png     ".png  [PNG graphics]"
>   TYPEALIAS .txt     ".txt  [Plain text]"
>   TYPEALIAS .cgi     ".cgi  [CGI scripts]"
>   TYPEALIAS .pl      ".pl   [Perl scripts]"
>   TYPEALIAS .css     ".css  [Cascading Style Sheets]"
>   TYPEALIAS .class   ".class [Java class files]"
>   TYPEALIAS .pdf     ".pdf  [Adobe Portable Document Format]"
>   TYPEALIAS .zip     ".zip  [Zip archives]"
>   TYPEALIAS .hqx     ".hqx  [Macintosh BinHex files]"
>   TYPEALIAS .exe     ".exe  [Executables]"
>   TYPEALIAS .wav     ".wav  [WAV sound files]"
>   TYPEALIAS .avi     ".avi  [AVI movies]"
>   TYPEALIAS .arc     ".arc  [Compressed archives]"
>   TYPEALIAS .mid     ".mid  [MIDI sound files]"
>   TYPEALIAS .mp3     ".mp3  [MP3 sound files]"
>   TYPEALIAS .doc     ".doc  [Microsoft Word document]"
>   TYPEALIAS .rtf     ".rtf  [Rich Text Format]"
>   TYPEALIAS .mov     ".mov  [Quick Time movie]"
>   TYPEALIAS .mpg     ".mpg  [MPEG movie]"
>   TYPEALIAS .mpeg    ".mpeg [MPEG movie]"
>   TYPEALIAS .asp     ".asp  [Active Server Pages]"
>   TYPEALIAS .jsp     ".jsp  [Java Server Pages]"
>   TYPEALIAS .cfm     ".cfm  [Cold Fusion]"
>   TYPEALIAS .php     ".php  [PHP]"
>   TYPEALIAS .js      ".js   [JavaScript code]"
>   
>   "#" x=General
>   "#" 1=Yearly  Q=Quarterly  m=Monthly      W=Weekly    D=Daily       d=DailySum
>   "#" H=Hourly  h=HourlySum  w=HoursOfWeek  4=15minly   6=15minlySum  5=5minly
>   "#" 7=5minlySum
>   "#" o=Domain  Z=Organisat. S=Host         s=RefSite   f=ReferrerURL
>   "#" n=SearchWord      N=SearchQuery       B=Browser   b=BrowserSum  p=OS
>   "#" i=Dir.    r=File       t=FileType     z=FileSize  c=Status
>   "#" I=Failure    L=FailHost     K=FailRef   E=Redir   l=RedirHost  k=RedirRef
>   "#" v=VHost   R=RedirVHost M=FailVHost    u=User      j=RedirUser   J=FailUser
>   "#" y=IntSearchWord   Y=IntSearchQuery    P=ProcTime
>   
>   WEEKBEGINSON MONDAY
>   MARKCHAR +
>   REPSEPCHAR none
>   COMPSEP " "
>   RAWBYTES OFF
>   BYTESDP 2
>   NOROBOTS ON
>   SEARCHCHARCONVERT ON
>   BARSTYLE i
>   PNGIMAGES ON
>   HTMLPAGEWIDTH 65
>   ASCIIPAGEWIDTH 76
>   MINGRAPHWIDTH 15
>   ALLCHART ON
>   ALLGRAPH P
>   
>   
>   "#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#"
>   "#" SERVICE REPORTS - HOW WELL WE ARE DELIVERING THE PAGES                      "#"
>   "#"                                                                             "#"
>   "#" Status - whether the pages were delivered okay, or failed                   "#"
>   "#" Proctime - time to dispatch files                                           "#"
>   "#" Failure - people requests these pages, and it failed                        "#"
>   "#" Failhost, Failref - failures arose from links on these hosts, on these URLs "#"
>   "#" Redir - people requested these files but were redirected                    "#"
>   "#" Redirhost, redirref - redirections arose from links on these hosts and URLs "#"
>   "#"                                                                             "#"
>   "#" COLS, CHART, SORTBY, FLOOR, SUB, ARGS, LINKINCLUDE - as above               "#"
>   "#" 304ISSUCCESS - 304 Not Modified means user saw a cached copy: i.e. success! "#"
>   "#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#""#"
>   
>   REPORTORDER x1QmWDdHwh4657oZSlLujJkKfsNnBbpvRMcPztiEIYyr
>   
>   DOMAIN ON
>   DOMCHART ON
>   DOMCOLS PQ
>   DOMSORTBY PAGES
>   DOMFLOOR -500p
>   SUBDOMAIN *.*.*.*
>   SUBDOMSORTBY PAGES
>   SUBDOMFLOOR 1.5%p
>   
>   DIRECTORY ON
>   DIRCHART ON
>   DIRCOLS PQc
>   "#" 
>   "#" Excluding all "local" and "images" directories, as per web team
>   "#" request.
>   "#"
>   DIREXCLUDE */local
>   DIREXCLUDE */images
>
>   "#"
>
>   DIRSORTBY PAGES7
>
>   SUBDIRSORTBY PAGES7
>
>   DIRFLOOR 0q
>
>   SUBDIRFLOOR 0q
>
>   SUBDIR /*/*/*/*/*
>   
>   FILETYPE ON
>   TYPECHART ON
>   TYPECOLS Rb
>   TYPESORTBY BYTES
>   SUBTYPE *.gz,*.Z
>   
>   SIZE ON
>   SIZECHART ON
>   SIZECOLS ScR
>   
>   ORGANISATION ON
>   ORGCHART ON
>   ORGCOLS Pb
>   ORGSORTBY PAGES
>   ORGFLOOR -500p
>   SUBORGSORTBY PAGES
>   SUBORG *.*.*.*.com
>   SUBORGFLOOR 25.0%p
>   
>   HOST ON
>   HOSTCHART ON
>   HOSTCOLS Pb
>   HOSTSORTBY PAGES
>   HOSTFLOOR -500p
>   
>   BROWSERREP ON
>   BROWREPCHART ON
>   BROWREPCOLS Rb
>   BROWREPSORTBY REQUESTS
>   BROWREPFLOOR -400r
>   
>   BROWSERSUM ON
>   BROWSUMCHART ON
>   BROWSUMCOLS PQq
>   BROWSUMSORTBY PAGES7
>   BROWSUMFLOOR -200q
>   SUBBROW */*/*/*
>   SUBBROWSORTBY PAGES7
>   SUBBROWFLOOR -400q
>   
>   STATUS ON
>   STATUSCHART ON
>   STATUSCOLS R
>   STATUSSORTBY ALPHABETICAL
>   STATUSFLOOR -200r
>   304ISSUCCESS ON
>   
>   OSREP ON
>   OSCHART ON
>   OSCHARTEXPAND Windows
>   OSCOLS PQq
>   OSSORTBY PAGES7
>   OSFLOOR -200q
>   SUBOSSORTBY PAGES7
>   SUBOSFLOOR -500q
>   
>   PROCTIME ON
>   PROCTIMECOLS R
>   PROCTIMECHART ON
>   
>   USER ON
>   USERCOLS Rb
>   USERCHART ON
>   USERSORTBY REQUESTS
>   USERFLOOR -500r
>   
>   REQUEST ON
>   REQCHART ON
>   REQCOLS RSc
>   REQSORTBY REQUESTS7
>   REQFLOOR 0.5%s
>   REQARGSSORTBY REQUESTS7
>   REQARGSFLOOR 0.5%s
>   REQEXCLUDE *
>   REQINCLUDE *.html
>   REQINCLUDE *.htm
>   REQINCLUDE *.zip
>   REQINCLUDE *.gz
>   REQINCLUDE *.Z
>   REQINCLUDE *.pdf
>
>   REQLINKEXCLUDE /cgi-bin/*
>   REQLINKEXCLUDE /scripts/*
>   REQLINKINCLUDE *
>   REQLINKINCLUDE *.zip
>   REQLINKINCLUDE *.pdf
>   
>   FAILURE ON
>   FAILCHART ON
>   FAILCOLS RS
>   FAILSORTBY REQUESTS7
>   FAILFLOOR -300s
>   FAILARGSSORTBY REQUESTS7
>   FAILARGSFLOOR 10s
>   FAILLINKEXCLUDE *
>   
>   FAILHOST ON
>   FAILHOSTCHART ON
>   FAILHOSTCOLS RS
>   FAILHOSTSORTBY REQUESTS7
>   FAILHOSTFLOOR -500s
>   
>   FAILUSER ON
>   FAILUSERCOLS R
>   FAILUSERCHART ON
>   FAILUSERSORTBY REQUESTS
>   FAILUSERFLOOR -400r
>   
>   FAILREF ON
>   FAILREFCHART ON
>   FAILREFCOLS RS
>   FAILREFSORTBY REQUESTS7
>   FAILREFFLOOR -300s
>   FAILREFARGSSORTBY REQUESTS7
>   FAILREFARGSFLOOR 10s
>   FAILREFLINKINCLUDE *
>   
>   REDIR ON
>   REDIRCHART ON
>   REDIRCOLS SR
>   REDIRSORTBY REQUESTS7
>   REDIRFLOOR -300s
>   REDIRARGSSORTBY REQUESTS7
>   REDIRARGSFLOOR 500s
>   
>   REDIRHOST ON
>   REDIRHOSTCHART ON
>   REDIRHOSTCOLS SR
>   REDIRHOSTSORTBY REQUESTS7
>   REDIRHOSTFLOOR -500s
>   
>   REDIRREF ON
>   REDIRREFCHART ON
>   REDIRREFCOLS RS
>   REDIRREFSORTBY REQUESTS7
>   REDIRREFFLOOR -300s
>   REDIRREFARGSSORTBY REQUESTS7
>   REDIRREFARGSFLOOR 500s
>   REDIRREFLINKINCLUDE *
>   
>   REFSITE ON
>   REFSITECHART ON
>   REFSITECOLS PQ
>   REFSITESORTBY PAGES7
>   REFSITEFLOOR -500q
>   REFDIRSORTBY PAGES7
>   REFDIRFLOOR 50.5%q
>   
>   REFERRER ON
>   REFCHART ON
>   REFCOLS PQ
>   REFSORTBY PAGES7
>   REFLINKINCLUDE *
>   REFFLOOR -500q
>   REFARGSSORTBY PAGES7
>   REFARGSFLOOR 50.5%q
>   
>   VHOST ON
>   VHOSTCHART ON
>   VHOSTCOLS Rb
>   VHOSTFLOOR -200b
>   VHOSTSORTBY BYTES
>   
>   REDIRVHOST ON
>   REDIRVHOSTCHART ON
>   REDIRVHOSTCOLS R
>   REDIRVHOSTFLOOR -200r
>   REDIRVHOSTSORTBY REQUESTS
>   
>   REDIRUSER ON
>   REDIRUSERCOLS R
>   REDIRUSERCHART ON
>   REDIRUSERSORTBY REQUESTS
>   REDIRUSERFLOOR -200r
>   
>   SEARCHWORD ON
>   SEARCHWORDCHART ON
>   SEARCHWORDCOLS PQq
>   SEARCHWORDSORTBY PAGES7
>   SEARCHWORDFLOOR 1.5%q
>   
>   SEARCHQUERY ON
>   SEARCHQUERYCHART ON
>   SEARCHQUERYCOLS Q
>   SEARCHQUERYSORTBY PAGES7
>   SEARCHQUERYFLOOR -500q
>   
>   INTSEARCHQUERY ON
>   INTSEARCHQUERYCOLS R
>   INTSEARCHQUERYCHART ON
>   INTSEARCHQUERYFLOOR -300r
>   INTSEARCHQUERYSORTBY REQUESTS
>   
>   INTSEARCHWORD ON
>   INTSEARCHWORDCOLS R
>   INTSEARCHWORDCHART ON
>   INTSEARCHWORDFLOOR -400r
>   INTSEARCHWORDSORTBY REQUESTS

Again, hope this helps as well and good luck, mate!

Answer (score 0):

For customized parsing of log files, there is a good script posted at http://www.biterscripting.com/SS_WebLogParser.html . It is written for web server logs, but you can use it as a starting point for writing your own log parser for logs of any kind.

Patrick